# Odoo decimal precision based on Unit Of Measure

Tags: python, floating-point, odoo, decimal-precision

Anybody an idea how to set the decimal precision of a product based on the unit of measure it is sold it.
For example product X sold in Kg has a decimal precision of 3 => Qty: 10.000Kg
Product Y sold in Unit(s) had a decimal precision of 0 -> Qty: 10 Unit(s)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer help you @Jesse?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
import odoo.addons.decimal_precision as dp
lost_qty = fields.Float('Lost Qty',  compute = '_compute_lost_qty',  digits = dp.get_precision('Product Unit of Measure'))
```

- You can also find these decimal precision in Odoo configuration Settings -> Database Structure -> Decimal Accuracy

Answer (score 0):

Import this at the top of your `.py` file:

```
from openerp.tools.float_utils import float_round
```

Now, imagine you have a product recordset (object/group of objects of products) in `self`:

```
your_quantity = 10.000
rounding = self.uom_id.rounding
qty = float_round(your_quantity, precision_rounding=rounding)
```

Comment: This can work but then I have to implement this in every model there is...